# Assigning a new value to a dictionary key in a in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value

I was trying to assign a new value to the key **x_position** in dictionary **alien_0** but the method I figured causes a TypeError
My Code:

```
alien_0={ 'x_position' : '25' , 'y_position' : '25' , 'speed' : 'medium' }
print(f"original position of alien is {alien_0['x_position']}")
if alien_0['speed'] == 'fast' :
    x_increment = 3

elif alien_0['speed'] == 'medium' :
    x_increment = 2

else:
    x_increment = 1   
#ladies and gentlemen in this case we have a slow alien

alien_0['x_position'] = alien_0['x_position'] + x_increment
print(f"our alien is at {alien_0['x_position']}")
```

Desired output:

original position of the alien is 25

our alien is at 27

Comment: Your positions are strings, they need to be integers

Comment: Please always include the **complete** error traceback in your question.

Comment: Remove the quotes around `x_position` (and probably `y_position` too) in `alien_0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in line 13:

```
alien_0['x_position'] = alien_0['x_position'] + x_increment
```

You are trying to add `x_increment` to `alien_0['x_position']`, but `alien_0['x_position']` is a string, while `x_increment` is an integer. Python will throw a type error.

As a sidenote, you can use the += operator rather than what you are doing now, writing this instead (it's equivalent):

```
alien_0['x_position'] += x_increment
```

Anyways, to fix this problem, you can simply make `alien_0['x_position']` an integer (if you wrap it with quotes, python will treat it as a string) when you define `alien_0` on line 1:

```
alien_0={ 'x_position' : 25 , 'y_position' : 25, 'speed' : 'medium' }
```

Just remove the quotes around `x_position`, and python will treat it as an integer. I'm assuming you are doing something similar with `y_position`, so you might want to remove the quotation marks around that too.

Output:

```
original position of alien is 25
our alien is at 27

[Program finished]
```

Fixed code:

```
alien_0={ 'x_position' : 25 , 'y_position' : 25 , 'speed' : 'medium' }
print(f"original position of alien is {alien_0['x_position']}")
if alien_0['speed'] == 'fast' :
    x_increment = 3

elif alien_0['speed'] == 'medium' :
    x_increment = 2

else:
    x_increment = 1   
#ladies and gentlemen in this case we have a slow alien

alien_0['x_position'] += x_increment
print(f"our alien is at {alien_0['x_position']}")
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the code replace `alien_0['x_position'] = alien_0['x_position'] + x_increment`  with `alien_0['x_position'] = int(alien_0['x_position']) + x_increment`

Answer (score 0):

The numbers in your dictionary are actually saved as text, you should remove the quotes ('') around the numbers in your dictionary.